# checkbox for Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Возможно ли сделать checkbox (как HTML страницах) в Телеграмм боте. Просто хочу задать вопрос и юсер смог выбрать несколько вариантов. Создаю ботов в Питон. Прошу подсказать если возможно! Спасибо!

Comment: можно отправить опрос с вопросом и вариантами ответа. Либо использовать inline кнопки

Comment: Да Вы правы, а как использовать метод выбора несколько ответов в inline кнопках.... Так как в вопросах возможно несколько ответов.